# Soundfonts on Android

Tags: android, audio, midi, soundfont

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use soundfonts on android (that have a .sf2 extension). I looked into JET Creator but it seems really complicated for simply playing soundfonts. I don't need to have interactive music as provided by JET, I just need to be able to play different notes of the soundfont on command when necessary. Any advice/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. You can playback midi files with mediaplayer, but you'll have to generate them yourselves, and you cannot supply a soundfont to it.