# Android - Play SoundFont with MIDI file

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, midi, synthesizer, soundfont

I have one midi file and I have played that midi file using MediaPlayer in android using the following code:

```
val mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.test_ring_1)

mMediaPlayer?.start()
```

It default play with one instrument like piano, now I want to add soundfont (sf2/sf3) file to play the midi notes with different instrument and with reverberation effects.

Please guide a way to achieve expected result.

Comment: have you seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6006363/4079010)?

Comment: @RahulKhurana The answer seems 8 years old, so there is huge amount of possibilities with latest technologies and updates.

Comment: This can be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193250/android-6-0-marshmallow-how-to-play-midi-notes

Comment: fluidsynth may help. https://github.com/FluidSynth/fluidsynth/wiki/BuildingForAndroid http://www.fluidsynth.org/

Answer (score 2):

There are two libraries that will be used to play a midi file using SoundFont.

[Midi Driver](https://github.com/KyoSherlock/MidiDriver)

Just a synthesizer for playing MIDI note on Android. You can use it with USB/Bluetooth-MIDI library together to create your MIDI application.

SoundFont2 file is supported.

[Android MIDI Library](https://github.com/LeffelMania/android-midi-lib)

This library provides an interface to read, manipulate, and write MIDI files. "Playback" is supported as a real-time event dispatch system. This library does NOT include actual audio playback or device interfacing.

**To initialize SF2-SoundBank**

```
SF2Soundbank sf = new SF2Soundbank(getAssets().open("test.sf2"));
        synth = new SoftSynthesizer();
        synth.open();
        synth.loadAllInstruments(sf);
        synth.getChannels()[0].programChange(0);
        synth.getChannels()[1].programChange(1);
        recv = synth.getReceiver();
```

**To Play the Midi notes from midi file**

```
MidiFile midiFile = new MidiFile(getAssets().open("test.mid"));

// Create a new MidiProcessor:
MidiProcessor processor = new MidiProcessor(midiFile);

// listen for all midi events:
processor.registerEventListener(new MidiEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStart(boolean fromBeginning) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(MidiEvent event, long ms) {

        if (event.getClass() == NoteOn.class) {

                NoteOn noteOn = ((NoteOn) event);

                try {
                    ShortMessage msg = new ShortMessage();
                    msg.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, channel, noteOn.getNoteValue(), noteOn.getVelocity());
                    recv.send(msg, ms);
                } catch (InvalidMidiDataException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else if (event.getClass() == NoteOff.class) {

                NoteOff noteOff = ((NoteOff) event);

                try {
                    ShortMessage msg = new ShortMessage();
                    msg.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, channel, noteOff.getNoteValue(), noteOff.getVelocity());
                    recv.send(msg, ms);
                } catch (InvalidMidiDataException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(boolean finished) {

    }
}, MidiEvent.class);

// Start the processor:
processor.start();
```

**Variable to define SF channel**

```
private int channel = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this it is working

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        SF2Soundbank sf = new SF2Soundbank(getAssets().open("SmallTimGM6mb.sf2"));
        synth = new SoftSynthesizer();
        synth.open();
        synth.loadAllInstruments(sf);
        synth.getChannels()[0].programChange(0);
        synth.getChannels()[1].programChange(1);
        recv = synth.getReceiver();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    this.findViewById(R.id.piano).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                try {
                    ShortMessage msg = new ShortMessage();
                    msg.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, 0, 60, 127);
                    recv.send(msg, -1);
                } catch (InvalidMidiDataException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                try {
                    ShortMessage msg = new ShortMessage();
                    msg.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, 0, 60, 127);
                    recv.send(msg, -1);
                } catch (InvalidMidiDataException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    this.findViewById(R.id.woodblock).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                try {
                    ShortMessage msg = new ShortMessage();
                    msg.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, 1, 60, 127);
                    recv.send(msg, -1);
                } catch (InvalidMidiDataException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                try {
                    ShortMessage msg = new ShortMessage();
                    msg.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, 1, 60, 127);
                    recv.send(msg, -1);
                } catch (InvalidMidiDataException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Dont forget to include sherlockmidi library from below repository, sample is also available in below repository.

https://github.com/agangzz/SherlockMidi

Comment: I want to play a midi file instead of getting input from the user.
is there any way to add the midi file?

Comment: Unfortunately agangzz/SherlockMidi is a fork of KyoSherlock/MidiDriver, which has been improperly licensed. I wouldnt' risk using it until this issue is resolved: https://github.com/KyoSherlock/MidiDriver/issues/8