# Virtual synthesizer in Android (based on jar) - native jni?

Tags: android, audio, java-native-interface, midi, javax.sound.midi

I am trying to load & use virtual (soft) synthesizer of java in Android. I read **Gervill** jar is to be used for this.
Other building block is **javax-sound** present in my project as an aar file (as is it not present in trimmed Java package of Android)

Gradle file inclusions are

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mmm.ttt"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(path: ':javax-sound')
    implementation project(path: ':gervilljar')         // This is folder name at project root folder level containing gervill.jar
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

#### Problem areas of code

**Code 1**

```
MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo().size    //results in an empty array in all cases
```

Some answers suggest only inclusion of gervill jar is enough for auto detection.
But since that hasnt worked for me, I written this

**Code 2**

```
var synth = SoftSynthesizer() as Synthesizer
        MidiSystem.addSynthesizer(synth)
```

I get compilation error for this

```
Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class com.sun.media.sound.SoftSynthesizer, unresolved supertypes: com.sun.media.sound.ReferenceCountingDevice
    class com.sun.media.sound.AudioSynthesizer, unresolved supertypes: javax.sound.midi.Synthesizer
```

**Code 3**

```
var synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer()
synth?.open()
```

With inclusion to gradle as above,
this is the run time error in absence of code 2

```
Caused by: jp.kshoji.javax.sound.midi.MidiUnavailableException: Synthesizer not found
        at jp.kshoji.javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSynthesizer(MidiSystem.java:323)
```

I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/38749847/1029110 for adding aar/jar files
But, havent linked each other in the module dependency gradle (Should/How to do that?) although gervill needs javax.sound

Final aim is to load & play soundfont files.
Avoiding native jni code if possible.

**EDIT**

1 problem identified. Gervill.jar is not good enough to work error free.
So I a picked few other classes from com.sun.media.sound.* and compiled into new jar. Now that error in code 2 (`unresolved supertypes`) has gone away.

Next trial was to include Android midi service

```
val midiManager = context.getSystemService(Context.MIDI_SERVICE) as android.media.midi.MidiManager
midiManager.getDevices()
```

This gave 2 services depending on the external applications installed on mobile. But they are not linked to the softsynthesizer in anyway.
  
So, Code 1 still has empty array for MidiDeviceInfo.
  
Part of Code 3: `synth?.open()` still failing badly, but with newer error.
**(Currently stuck here)**

```
Caused by: jp.kshoji.javax.sound.midi.MidiUnavailableException: Can not open line
        at com.sun.media.sound.SoftSynthesizer.open(SoftSynthesizer.java:1132)
        at com.sun.media.sound.SoftSynthesizer.open(SoftSynthesizer.java:1036)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching interface jp.kshoji.SourceDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian is supported.
        at jp.kshoji.javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getLine(AudioSystem.java:475)
        at jp.kshoji.javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(AudioSystem.java:602)
        at com.sun.media.sound.SoftSynthesizer.open(SoftSynthesizer.java:1066)
        at com.sun.media.sound.SoftSynthesizer.open(SoftSynthesizer.java:1036)
```

**Code 4:**

```
jp.kshoji.javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSoundbank(File("soundfont.sf2"))
```

Fails with

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: not implemented.
    at jp.kshoji.javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSoundbank(MidiSystem.java:277)
```

I have checked the Java for windows version source code. There is no override or implementation of the file to use getSoundbank.

*Fixes & future steps?*

Comment: renamed folder name and project values from gervilljar to gervill
`implementation project(path: ':gervill')`
Still same error as in code 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions in my understanding

#### Code 3.

[github.com/KyoSherlock/MidiDriver](https://github.com/KyoSherlock/MidiDriver) is the android ready code which has same contents of com.sun.media.sound & jp\kshoji\javax\sound\midi put together. Also trimmed to exclude unwanted classes.

Other midi drivers like

- https://github.com/billthefarmer/mididriver
- https://github.com/pedrolcl/android/tree/master/NativeGMSynth

are based on native C/C++ code, which I avoided all along.

This answer helped https://stackoverflow.com/a/56700883/1029110

#### Code 4.

Call to load soundbank should be done via SF2SoundBank & not via MidiSystem.getSoundbank(soundFontFile)

```
val sf = SF2Soundbank(assets.open("SmallTimGM6mb.sf2"))
```

#### Code 1.

Might not be important for producing sounds via phone speaker, as even the KyoSherlock running sample returns 0

In depth reading can be done here 
http://jsresources.sourceforge.net/faq_midi.html